# Select2 doesn't apply on select element

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

`Select2` is simply not applied on the custom html select. No errors thrown as well.

```
$("#product").select2();
```

This renders absolutely the normal html select element. Again, no single error in the console. Any idea? Could it be because of the `3.3.1` version of jQuery? Thank you!

Comment: is there any duplicate element with same id

Comment: `Could it be because of the 3.3.1 version of jQuery?` No. Select2 is compatible with the latest jQuery versions. Check the console for errors, and make sure you have only 1 element in the DOM with the `#product` id and are running your jQuery code *after* the DOM has loaded.

Comment: Can you create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/356679/1823841) here.

Comment: Hae you included the select2 js file?